# Rendering math formulas: algorithms

Tags: c++, linux, macos

how I can make simple application for render math formulas to image file? I didn't found anything for this from internet.  If you know something, show me algorithms or source code :) Best regards

Comment: Do you want to render formulas (like "y = x") or plot the graphs of functions? (The question is off-topic or too broad regardless, but you need to search for the right thing if you want to find it.)

Comment: Seriously you searched ? What are you starting with ? LaTeX ? mml ? How is this related to programming ?

Comment: @cmbarbu I know about latex, but can I use this libs in my c++ code?

Comment: @molbdnilo first variant, like y = x.

Answer (score 0):

gnuplot. Ready application to draw math formulas to Image files.

Comment: I have my symbol-differentiation application, and i want render result of this application to image file. I guess  gnuplot-library for rendering graphics. :)